# 'Teleworking' or 'remote work'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am reading a book for learning business English, reading the text from the book I came across the term "teleworking", which is in essence a remote work.

I've seen the term "remote work" various times, but I've never seen something like "teleworking".

So my question is: is teleworking widely used and is this word topical? Because, when I want to find vacancies, they normally use "remote work" or "remote working". Thanks.

Comment: Off topic: I encourage you to always say "want to" and not "wanna", at least when using this website. Because this site is about learning English, it helps if everybody writes in their best attempt at correct English, grammar, punctuation and capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

Anecdotally, and in my recent experience (in North America), the most common noun and verb is increasingly 'telecommute'. People would know what you mean if you said 'teleworking', but it is not nearly such a common term where I live.

You can see a [Google Ngram comparison of the popularity of the various words and phrases](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=telecommuting%2Cteleworking%2Cremote%20working&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctelecommuting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteleworking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremote%20working%3B%2Cc0).

That said, an NGram comparing 'telecommute' and 'telework' instead of 'telecommuting' and 'teleworking' [produces the reverse result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=telecommute%2C%20telework%2C%20remote%20work&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctelecommute%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctelework%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cremote%20work%3B%2Cc0).

However, because telecommuting is still a relatively new concept that is only now becoming mainstream, it may well be that there are strong regional differences, and that the language is not yet firmly established.

For what it's worth, the Cambridge dictionary cites '[telework](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/teleworking)/[teleworker](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/teleworker)' as synonyms of 'telecommute/telecommuting'.

So my answer is that there is probably no firm answer. 'Telework', 'telecommute' or 'remote work' are all fine, and you may want to poll colleagues/coworkers for which word they are more familiar with.